# Congratulatory Messages

Tags: discussion, congratulations

As you all have probably noticed, I have started congratulating people for reaching point milestones. I've had some feedback on doing this, but wanted to formalize the feedback somewhat and ask for opinions.

Please answer back to this questions with what's going on in your head. Tell me if you think putting out congrats to people is a good idea.

I've also been asked to maybe cut back on the threshold levels. Here is a list of what I think congratulatory thresholds should be ... if you think it should be different (more/less occurrence), please let me know:

- 1000
- 5000
- 10k
- 25k
- 50k
- Every 50k after that

I was also wondering if you thought (if you agree with doing this in the first place) maybe having one thread of congratulations, where the question would be the placeholder and answers would actually be the congrats notices? Or should we continue to keep them separate as their own threads?

Give me your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

I think having one thread with multiple answers would be sensible, otherwise the whole meta area will be full of such threads - you've posted six already, in just a few days...

The thresholds on a non-beta site go ... 500, 1k, 2, 2.5, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, but that's probably too many thresholds for this purpose - the ones you have suggested seem sensible...

Comment: Thanks Nick ... I appreciate the input. I'm really wavering on one or many threads ... like it was a database or something (*one to many cardinality*).

Answer (score 2):

I like the logic, it's a bit more refined.  I'm stewing on the single question as a placeholder and thinking people wouldn't see add on 'answers' for individual congratulatory messages.  Nick C makes a good point that if it was done as individual posts then Meta would get potentially filled.

It's something to think about.

BUT...I like congratulating, it's a good thing to do, it validates their contributions to the site and I think that's important and helps to build a sense of community.

Update:

I'm for a one thread system.  Meta is getting filled.  As the site grows it will accelerate.

Comment: Yes, you have me waffling as well :D

Comment: I don't think there is a "filled" for either Meta or the main site. I don't know how long it will be sustainable with a rash of new people coming along. Jon Ericson did thank me for revitalizing Meta, though. I don't think it's an issue right now, but may be in the future. The only issue I have with "one thread" is that any congrats is going to get lost in the mix, so would be moot. If I make one thread with one answer per congrats, the new "answers" will fall to the bottom and nobody will see them ... wouldn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 2):

One thread is fine. Otherwise it will turn into a daily celebration. Like the monthly office birthday party, folks. :)

Comment: I smell the egg your cooking on that.  good point.

Comment: I'm microwaving fish on my cubicle today. ;)

Comment: Where you been?  Liked your answers.  Are you gone forever?

Comment: @Ppoggio Thanks for the nice words. I've just been busy with work. Not gone forever. I plan to continue contributing soon. Life just gets in the way! :)